# How can I remap keys for a remote desktop session in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, remote-desktop, remapping

My main machine runs Windows 7 and has <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> mapped to <kbd>Control</kbd>.

When I remote to this computer from other machines (particularly ones that I do not manage or have administrator access to), their keyboard's <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> does not work as a <kbd>Control</kbd>.

My question is if there is anyway around this? (One side note is I'd really like to stay away from running AutoHotKey if there are other options).

Answer (score 2):

You can download CapstoCtrl from SysInternals.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897578

> Ctrl2cap is a kernel-mode device driver that filters the system's
>   keyboard class driver in order to convert caps-lock characters into
>   control characters. People like myself that migrated to NT from UNIX
>   are used to having the control key located where the caps-lock key is
>   on the standard PC keyboard, so a utility like this is essential for
>   our editing well-being.

Comment: So does the kernel-model device driver cause the caps lock keystroke sent via RDP to be translated into a control keystroke? And have you tested this personally?

Comment: Tested this on Windows 7 and it did not work for me.

Comment: I don't agree with previous commenters, works for me on Windows 10 and XFreeRDP as the RDP client.